# How can I make a variable number of links using Flask and HTML?

Tags: python, html, flask

Let me explain my situation. I am making a note app using flask and HTML. I want it to be so that when you click on one of the links, it takes you to a link with the title, but it isn't working! I am using ArangoDB.
Here is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{welcome}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="section has-text-centered">
      <h1 class="title is-2">Hi {{username}}!</h1>
      <a href={{url_for('new')}} class="button is-rounded is-outlined is-primary">Create a note</a>
      <a href={{url_for('handle_logout')}} class="button is-rounded is-outlined is-danger">Log out</a>
    </section>
    <section>
      <ul>
        {% for note in notes %}
          <li>
            <a class="button is-light is-fullwidth" href="/{{note.title}}">{{note.title}}</a>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the relevant python code:

```
@app.route("/notes")
def notes_page():
    global notes
    notes = db.collection("Users")[username]["notes"]
    if username != "":        
        return render_template("notes.html", username=username, notes=notes, welcome=welcome)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("home"))

try:
    for i in notes:
        url = "/" + i["title"]
        @app.route(url)
        def view_note():
            return render_template("view.html", title=i["title"], note=i["note"])
except NameError:
    pass
```

I run the code and I clicked a link for a test note I created, and when I was redirected, it showed the 404 error message saying the link wasn't found. Can you please help me fix this? Thanks

Comment: Where are the other routes defined? (new and handle_logout)

Comment: You should convert the title into a url-compliant variant (slugify). 
All non-conforming characters are replaced. You can do this either using a 
library or by hand. The resulting identification is then added to the note in the 
database so that you can query the note on the basis of this. The converted title 
is used within the [rule](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) 
for the route, so that it is extracted and transferred as a variable when called up.